# PowerPoint VBA: open a text file and show each line on a seperate slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want PowerPoint to open an external text file and show line 1 of this file on slide 1 of my presentation, line 2 on slide 2, etc.

If the number of slides is larger than the number of lines in the text file, I would like to start at line 1 again.

Here's what I have so far (mixed code and pseudocode):

```
Dim FileName, FSO, MyFile
FileName = "C:\test.txt"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(FileName, 1)

For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count

  If LINE(i) EXISTS IN TEXT FILE THEN

    ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes("myshape").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = LINE(i)

  ELSE START AT LINE(1) AGAIN

  End If

Next

MyFile.Close
```

How do I refer to the lines in the text file using `i`, and what would be the best way to do the if/then-statement?

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like a request to do the work more than a technical question...what is the point that blocks you ?

Comment: iDevlop: you were right. I've edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Please understand I cannot do the whole thing for you but the logic somehow looks like this:

```
MoreSlides = true
While moreSlides

        Open "mytextfile.txt" For Input As 1
        While Not EOF(1) and moreSlides
            Line Input #1, myline

            ' here comes the part inserting the line in the next slide
            ' You set moreSlides to false if you reach the end

         Wend
         close #1

Wend
```